# Chi-Squared test in Python

Tags: python, r, scipy

I've used the following code in `R` to determine how well observed values (20, 20, 0 and 0 for example) fit expected values/ratios (25% for each of the four cases, for example):

```
> chisq.test(c(20,20,0,0), p=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(20, 20, 0, 0)

X-squared = 40, df = 3, p-value = 1.066e-08
```

How can I replicate this in Python? I've tried using the `chisquare` function from `scipy` but the results I obtained were very different; I'm not sure if this is even the correct function to use. I've searched through the `scipy` documentation, but it's quite daunting as it runs to 1000+ pages; the `numpy` documentation is almost 50% more than that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`scipy.stats.chisquare`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare.html) expects observed and expected absolute frequencies, not ratios. You can obtain what you want with

```
>>> observed = np.array([20., 20., 0., 0.])
>>> expected = np.array([.25, .25, .25, .25]) * np.sum(observed)
>>> chisquare(observed, expected)
(40.0, 1.065509033425585e-08)
```

Although in the case that the expected values are uniformly distributed over the classes, you can leave out the computation of the expected values:

```
>>> chisquare(observed)
(40.0, 1.065509033425585e-08)
```

The first returned value is the χ² statistic, the second the *p*-value of the test.

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly what I needed :) I did try converting the *observed* values to ratios, but must have misread the documentation as the function wants *frequencies*, not ratios. Some expected frequencies will not be equal, so I guess I should have chosen a different example :)

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to point out that while the answer appears to be correct syntactically, you should not be using a Chi-squared distribution with your example because you have observed frequencies that are too small for an accurate Chi-square test.

"This test is invalid when the observed or expected frequencies in each category are too small. A typical rule is that all of the observed and expected frequencies should be at least 5." see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html#scipy.stats.chisquare

Comment: To my knowledge, the rule is based on the *expected* frequencies only, not on the observed frequencies, so this example (with expected frequencies all equal to 10) should be OK. R gives a warning if the *expected* frequencies are too small ... For example, http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780199219995.pdf ; http://www.stat.sfu.ca/~cschwarz/Stat-650/Notes%/PDFbigbook-JMP/JMP-part016.pdf ; http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statsmall.html (results of googling "chi-squared expected 'rule of thumb'").  I won't downvote you because you are correctly quoting the (incorrect???) Scipy documentation ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I might add that there only need be expected frequencies of at least 5 for 80% of classes.

Comment: That depends on how accurate you want the approximation to be. In my experience the "*all* expected frequencies >=5" rule of thumb is more commonly quoted.  The rule you quote is just a little more relaxed (citation/link, just for curiosity's sake?)

Comment: In the first link you provided (http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780199219995.pdf), it says to allow one-fifth, and also no expected frequencies of 0.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to call your R code from python. You can do this:

- by making an R script run as a command line tool. See [this link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) for more information on running R scripts form the command line using `Rscript`. From python you can then run an R script by executing a system call using either `subprocess` or `os.system`. Any data exchange is done through text or binary files. I like this approach because it is very simple, and it is easy to debug the R script separate from the python code. The downside is that all data goes through the harddrive, which could prove to be very slow.
- by using  [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy.html), or [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) to run R code directly from within python. In this way the integration is more tight, but this link also introduces its own little quirks. For example, in my experience debugging R code called through rpy is a little harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used `rpy` previously, but decided against it here as I may need to transfer quite a large amount of data with a complex structure.

Comment: Just wanted to add this option to the range of answers, maybe some other folks like this approach.